# Onclick event does not fire on table rows

Tags: javascript, html

The onclick event does not work, when the element changes on the first TD.
When you change the DOM of the first TD of TRs with the mouseover event, the click event stops firing.
(In the Google Chrome browser)

```js
  for(var i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        $("#table").append("<tr class='node' data-index='" + i + "'><td>case</td></td><td>.......</td></tr>");
    
    $("#table").on("mouseover", ".node", function(event){
        var number = $(this).data("index");
        $(this).children().first().html("<div style='width:auto;'>Number:" + number + "</div>");
    });

    $("#table").on("mouseout", ".node", function(event){
        $(this).children().first().html("case");
    });

    $("#table").on("click", ".node", function(event){
        var number = $(this).data("index");
        console.log(number);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="table" border = "1" style="margin: 0 auto;" width = "300" ></table>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. What browser are you using? Running the code snippet in Firefox continued to log the index number after hovering over the first TD in a row. If I have misunderstood the issue, please provide more detail in the question (not in comment). Also don't forget to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site - you even get a badge for it :-)

Comment: It works fine in Firefox, but flickers in Chrome.